# How to "unblock" class view in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, workspace

First time I am facing such problem in Eclipse. So I wanted to open a class, used a shortcut ctrl+shift+r, typed class name and tried to open it. After i clicked on it,it didn't showed code in central panel. Yesterday when I was working on this class I did had a code that I worked on...

Comment: Generally, you should open classes with "open type" instead of "open resource".

Comment: Will take a look on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Alright, solved. View of the class was actually on a second screen, so minimalized that it was looking like a cursor or really narrow line...